# Regulating Flow of Dropbox Datastore Sync and Delta Size Error

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

Wow, that title was a mouthful. Allow me to explain.

I migrated a few thousand records via SQLite to a **local** Dropbox Datastore. Then when I connect to Dropbox, and migrate the records to a **remote** datastore, I initiate a `sync` and get this error:

`[ERROR] db: database_manager.cpp:1354: datastore op PutDeltaOp(dsid=default, rev=0->1, nonce=PszHI1QeepzsrB9IqqrFtg) failed: put_delta error response 400: Error: put_delta of delta (size 4138303) exceeds size limit 2097152 bytes`

I understand that the sync has a size limit on it so that only so much gets sent to the Dropbox server at a time. But if I have N local records, how do I tell Dropbox to sync without choking on the size/number of records? At this point they are Datastore records, and I assumed Dropbox would manage the sync on its own.

Any ideas how I regulate the sync of data so I don't exceed the limit?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to watch the count and size as you add records to make sure you don't go over the [limits](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/ios) before calling [`sync`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/ios#DBDatastore.sync:). You can check the current size of unsynced changes using `DBDatastore. unsyncedChangesSize`:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/ios#DBDatastore.unsyncedChangesSize

Comment: Hmm... let me see if I understand. The only thing `sync` does is merge the delta cache with the datastore, right? So whether the datastore is **local** or **remote** doesn't matter. They both have to be `sync`ed the same way. Is that correct?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I added a bunch of records while the datastore was still **local**, and the above error only happened once I migrated to a remote datastore and tried syncing with the server.

Comment: Also, if you have an example on how to use `unsyncedChangesSize`, that would be great. When searching for it on Google, there are 3 search results, 2 of which are API documentation. :)

Comment: Yes, both local and remote datastores require you to call `sync` to commit your changes. (In the remote case, that immediately enqueues the changes to be sent to the server, and in the local case those changes are just persisted to be uploaded if/when you migrate to a remote datastore.) I think it makes sense that you only got that error after migrating, since that's the first time the changes are sent to the server. You'll need to `sync` in smaller chunks to keep the delta size small. I don't have an example of using `unsyncedChangesSize`, but I hope it's straightforward?

Comment: Thanks, @smarx. I am now syncing in smaller intervals prior to storing the records in the datastore. I checked `unsyncedChangesSize` on each sync and it never exceeded 200k. Interestingly, if I am already linked to a Dropbox account, the records sync to the server with no errors. If I connect to Dropbox **after** adding the records, I get the above error again. It seems the datastore migration is ignoring the sync intervals and trying to push it all to the server at once. Does that make sense?

Comment: I submitted a support request to the Dropbox team with a sample project that demonstrates the issue. Thanks.